# Creating panel in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, panel, xul

in my xul file:

```
<!DOCTYPE overlay >
<overlay id="custombutton-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<script src="browserOverlay.js"/>

<!-- Firefox -->
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
  <toolbarbutton id="custom-button-1"/>
</toolbarpalette>


<!-- button details -->
<toolbarbutton id="custom-button-1"
  label="Custom"
  tooltiptext="My custom toolbar button"
  oncommand="xyz.showPanel()"
  class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional custombutton"
/>

<panel id="thepanel">
  <hbox align="start">
    <image src="warning.png"/>
    <vbox>
      <description value="You have 6 new messages."/>
      <hbox>
        <button label="Read Mail"/>
        <button label="New Message"/>
      </hbox>
    </vbox>
  </hbox>
</panel>

</overlay>
```

when calling the function "xyz.showPanel()" which has the following code:

```
var xyz = {
    showPanel: function (e)
    {
        var button = document.getElementById('custom-button-1');
        var panel = document.getElementById('thepanel');
        panel.openPopup(button, 'after_start', 0, 0, false, false);

    }
}
```

it gives me  error in the error console that says:

> Error: TypeError: panel is null

I want to show a panel like "Downloads" toolbar button in Firefox

I am new to Firefox addons,

so how to show a panel when clicking on toolbar button ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In overlays, the first level of nested elements must refer to something already in the DOM (the element stuff will be added to), or else these elements will be ignored. (Some exceptions to that rule, like `<script>`.)

Your panel definition basically says (contrary to what you want it to say)

- Find an *existing* `panel` with id "thepanel"
- If found, add a `hbox` and its children to the panel
- If not, ignore the subtree.

You need to change your XUL to provide a container for your panel, e.g. `#mainPopupSet`, like you did with `#BrowserToolbarPalette` for your `toolbarbutton`.

```
<overlay ...>
...
<popupset id="mainPopupSet">
  <panel id="thepanel">
    ...
  </panel>
</popupset>
</overlay>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, You have added a big Milestone of my  learning path :) . I added the "toolbarbutton" in the "<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">" because the tutorial said so, so how can I find what element be placed in which containers, i.e. how did you find that I should put the panel in the "popupset", is there a reference or something, because Mozilla tutorial is very complicated :( ??

Comment: You'd usually look into `browser.xul` or whatever window you are overlaying to figure out a good place to put your elements. It depends on the element, of course. Toolbar buttons into the main pallete, panels usually into the main popupset, urlbar icons into the urlbar, obviously, etc. The [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) helps with this, and so does reading the code in [MXR](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/base/content/browser.xul), or opening chrome://browser/content/browser.xul and doing a View Source.